# Is (Java) XSLT Transformation capable of multi threading?

Tags: multithreading, xslt

Sources tell me that Java XSLT Transformations are "single threaded" and will "block" cores from executing other code until the Transformation is completed.

However I cannot find other independent Sources in the Net that will support this claim.

Can anyone clarify this?

**Sources:**

> XSLT is typically single-threaded and 100% CPU-bound (including memory
>   bus). If it takes 250ms, that means it will process 8 pages per second
>   (2 CPUs x (1 second * (1000 millis / second) / 250 millis)). If think
>   time is 10 seconds, that application will support less than 80
>   concurrent users (probably 60 in reality)

[by Cameron Purdy on theserverside.com](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=17866)

> An instance of the Transformer class is then created to perform the
>   actual transformation. Unlike the stylesheet itself, the transformer
>   cannot be shared by many clients and is not thread-safe.

[from O'REILLY Java and XSLT](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch05_01.htm)

> newTransformer (...) Returns: A Transformer object that may be used to perform a
>   transformation in a single Thread, never null.

[from Java 6 API TransformerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html)

Comment: What sources have you read?  Please edit your questions to provide links to your sources.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing more specific, I will edit the question shortly. I thought that if such a problem persisted it would be known to those with greater experience in this field.

Comment: "XSLT Transformations are "single threaded": true. "... ad will "block" cores": false.

Answer (score 1):

I am as certain as I can be without a post from Michael Kay but...

No - cores will not be blocked from executing other code

This has nothing to do with XSLT. All modern operating systems and cpu's implement preemptive multithreading. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Multithreading.

This prevents any process from blocking a cpu.

Answer (score 1):

A very delayed response, but anyone coming here for information might be interested to read my XML Prague 2015 paper on multithreading in the Saxon processor:

https://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2015mhk.pdf

I have no idea whether the Xalan processor (the one built in to the JDK) does any internal multithreading.